# Using React Native as a framework

Tags: ios, react-native

When I `react-native init myProject`, I get `xcode` project with `react-native` inside as a library.

How can I use `react-native` as an `iOS` `framework`?

Or, is there someone who use all `react-native` `libraries` as a framework and not as defaults `libraries`?

Does `react-native` awesome team have had some walk-around this case? Any `github` issue? I didn't find a thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if it can be used be with existing native apps ? If so yes https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html